# Why Spring Bean Self Invocation is working here for Transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

**Environment  :**

Tomcat 6

Spring 4

Hibernate 4

Spring MVC

**Code  :**

I have below service layer class :

```
public interface AbhisheskService {
    public List<AbhishekDTO> findByMatchingCriteria(AbhishekDetailsSearchDTO searchDto);

}

@Service("abhishekService")
public class AbhishekServiceImpl implements AbhisheskService {


    @Autowired
    private AbhishekDao abhishekDao;    

    @Transactional
    public List<AbhishekDTO> findByMatchingCriteria(AbhishekDetailsSearchDTO searchDto) {
        return getAbs();
    }   


    public List<AbhishekDTO> getAbs(){
        Abhishekdetails absDt = this.abhishekDao.get(4L);
        return null;
    }

}
```

The AbhishekDao is a standard DAO layer interface which extends GenericDAO super interface.

```
public interface AbhishekDao extends GenericDAO<Abhishekdetails, Long>{

    public List<Abhishekdetails> findByMatchingCriteria(AbhishekDetailsSearchDTO searchDto);

}
```

My question is :

`findByMatchingCriteria` method is marked with `@Transactional.`

This method calls another method `getAbs` which is NOT MARKED AS `@Transactional` and it is invoked within findByMatchingCriteria (self-invocation).

As per my understanding since :

1)`findByMatchingCriteria` is calling `getAbs` within itself (self-invocation) , `getAbs`() method **SHOULD NOT** run inside transaction. Since it is bypassing dynamically created proxy here

2)Moreever getAbs doesn't have `@Transactional` annotation on it.

3)But when `getAbs` calls `this.abhishekDao.get(4L)` everything works fine and a record with `ID 4L` is retrieved. The DAO bean is calling `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` inside it to get object from Db. But why is this working ? 
Since there **SHOULD NOT BE** any active transaction.

4)Why is above code working ?  A lot of posts on Spring Transaction management state that self invocation will not work. (Even spring docs).

Then why is above set up working ?

Am I amissing anything here ?

Or My understanding of spring transaction is incorrect?

Please repply as I am getting confused here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way it works is:
- AbhishekServiceImpl bean is wrapped in a proxy.

- `findByMatchingCriteria` is `@Transactional`, so before the method is invoked Spring gets new database connection from the connection pool and sets auto commit to false.
- The transactions are bound to a thread, so the other methods on this thread will use this connection.
- The methods `findByMatchingCriteria` and `getAbs` are executed
- after `findByMatchingCriteria` Spring calls commit on the connection(or rollback if `RuntimeException` occurs).

So your code is in transaction that's around `findByMatchingCriteria`

A case where a transaction will not be created is if you have @Transactional on `getAbs` , but not on `findByMatchingCriteria`(reverse the calling) and you call `findByMatchingCriteria` outside of the service. But if you call only `getAbs` outside of the service it will be in transaction.

More clear example:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{   
    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;    
    @Transactional
    public List<T> transactionalMethod() {
        return this.myDao.get(4L);
    }   
    public List<T> notTransactionalMethod(){
        return transactionalMethod();
    }
}
```

In some other class:

```
     @Component
        public class SomeClass {
            @Autowired
            private MyService myService;
            public void someMethod(){
                  myService.transactionalMethod();//will be in transaction. Here actualy you go to the proxy first and then it calls the real method. 
                  myService.notTransactionalMethod();//will not be in transaction and hibernate will throw an error. 
                                                     //You go to the proxy, but doesent do anything special because the method is not transactional and it calls the real method, 
                                                     //but here you dont't got trough the proxy so the @Transactional is ignored.
            }
        }
```